# Linking one php file to another with the built in server

Tags: php

I have one file, index.php, which has only:

```
<a href="http://localhost:8888/test.php">Test</a>
```

And I have another file, test.php, which has only:

```
<a href="http://localhost:8888/">home</a>
```

So the idea is, I could move back and forth between these two pages. I load it up by typing:

```
php -S localhost:8888 index.php
```

and I can get the index page. But when I click the "Test" link, all it does is reload index.php. But in the URL bar in the browser, it says "http://localhost:8888/test.php".

Why doesn't it just load up the test.php page? I feel like I'm taking crazy pills!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're specifying a file path in the command line, [the built-in web server will use it as a "router" script](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php#example-413) and always fetch it no matter what.

Omitting it should allow you to browse links:

```
php -S localhost:8888
```